# Selecting values based on a key value

Tags: jq

I have the following json output

```
{
         "metadata": {
            "guid": "f9787342b-0d3b-45c5-b7a6-f61c2a12de00",
            "url": "/v2/events/f67a342b-0d3b-45c5-b7a6-f61c2a12de00",
            "created_at": "2018-03-07T17:15:22Z",
            "updated_at": "2018-03-07T17:15:22Z"
         },
         "entity": {
            "type": "audit.app.update",
            "actor": "ae84a203-921d-41a0-97bf-26679342ef47",
            "actor_type": "user",
            "actor_name": "abc@xyz.org",
            "actor_username": "abc.xyz.org",
            "actee": "b9dba536-2aae-455d-aadc-8782bd5ee8d5",
            "actee_type": "app",
            "actee_name": "knpFileUpload",
            "timestamp": "2018-03-07T17:15:22Z",
            "metadata": {
               "request": {
                  "state": "STARTED"
               }
            },
            "space_guid": "bcz38b4b-9989-42d2-b6bd-702645e344cf",
            "organization_guid": "axr09940a-a680-4f54-af30-3abfdb76ea2f"
         }
      },
```

I am trying to get the value of updated_at if actee_type = app.

Tried the following command

```sh
cf curl  "/v2/events?q=space_guid:bcz38b4b-9989-42d2-b6bd-702645e344cf" | jq -r '.[] | select (.ressources[].entity.actor_type=="app") | .resources[].metadata.updated_at'
```

but getting an error that Cannot index number with string "ressources" and if I use

```sh
jq -r 'select (.ressources[].entity.actor_type=="app") | .resources[].metadata.updated_at'
```

```
Cannot iterate over null. Can someone suggest what is the correct syntax.
```

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a mismatch between the sample JSON and the rest of the question, e.g. the JSON has no key named "ressources", and the key corresponding to "app" is "actee_type" (not "actor_type" as in the jq filter).

Based on the sample JSON (minus the erroneous trailing comma) and the stated query, the appropriate jq filter would simply be:

```
select (.entity.actee_type=="app")
| .metadata.updated_at
```

with the result (using the -r command-line option):

```
2018-03-07T17:15:22Z
```

### Update

Based on the comment, the relevant query against the complete JSON would be as above but preceded by `.resources[] |`

Comment: Here's the complete JSON. 
` {
   "resources": [
      
      {
         "metadata": {
            "updated_at": "2018-03-07T17:15:22Z"
         },
         "entity": {
           "actor_name": "abc@xyz.org",
            "actor_username": "abc@xyz.org",
            "actee_type": "app",
            "actee_name": "knpCOSFileUpload",
            "timestamp": "2018-03-07T17:15:22Z",
            "metadata": {
               "request": {
                  "state": "STARTED"
               }
            },
         }
      }
   ]
}`

Comment: That's also not valid JSON. I'd suggest moving the corrected, complete JSON to the Q.

Comment: That gave me a start and I have modified it to get what I wanted. Thanks